# Command as default argument of macro

Tags: macros, mathjax

I'm able to create a macro without problems which takes a command as one of its arguments, eg:

```
\newcommand{formatnodefault}[2]{#1 #2}
% both of these work
\formatnodefault{\mathcal}{ABC}
\formatnodefault{\mathfrak}{ABC}
```

But when I try to give a default for the command, it still works when using the default but not when I explicitly pass in the command to use

```
\newcommand{formatdefault}[2][\mathcal]{#1 #2}
\formatdefault{ABC} % this works fine
\formatdefault{\mathfrak}{ABC} % this doesn't work
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong with entering/overriding the default here? If it matters, this is being processed by MathJax from a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `\formatdefault[\mathfrak]{ABC}` -- you're defining it with an optional argument, so `\mathfrak` should be inside that, otherwise it would try to call `\mathcal \mathfrak`. And you're missing a the backslash in `\newcommand`

Comment: Syntax, syntax, syntax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in LaTeX, but I am unsure about MathJax, which isn't TeX etc. anyway, apart from a similar syntax.

It should be called `\formatdefault[\mathfrak]{ABC}` otherwise `\formatdefault` would use `\mathcal \mathfrak`, taking `\mathfrak` to be the second argument whereas it was meant as first one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\formatdefault}[2][\mathcal]{#1{#2}}


\begin{document}


$\formatdefault{ABC}$ % this works fine
$\formatdefault[\mathfrak]{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It also works in MathJax.